# How can I select data from a table with specific attribute with pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:
`Country` , `Gdp` , `Year`, `Capital` , `Labor`.

It has data from `1950` to `2014`, but I want extract data from all rows with `year = 2000`.
I'm using python , pandas and numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print df
  Country  Gdp  Year Capital  Labor 
0       a   40  2001       s      40
1       b   30  2000       u      70
2       c   70  2008       t      50

print df[df['Year'] == 2000]
  Country  Gdp  Year Capital  Labor 
1       b   30  2000       u      70
```

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, but at that moment I didn't have permission because you solve my problem faster than, minimum time of accepting! 
thank you very much :)